# How to add unchanged code in Git

Tags: git, git-push

I have situation here at my work where we need to add and push couples files as a package. There is one particular file where there is no code change (same as master repo). Git is not recognizing the file and so I am not able to add and push.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this because of how Git works (based on hashing files). You could just add a newline somewhere. Although I don't completely see why you'd need to have a single push represent a package.

Comment: define "not recognizing". every commit is a changeset. if no change occurs to that file at this particular commit, then no reason to add that file to the commit. it would be an empty diff anyway if possible.

Comment: Why do you need to "push" a file that is not changed? Its version residing in the remote repository is already the latest.

Comment: basically we want to migrate our code as package or (in commit code) so there might be some code which hasn't change but have to go in this package so that when we checkout in UAT we get all the files associate with that commit code.

Comment: Commits are complete snapshots.  They're a(n organized) list of what content goes at what path.  If the content you want a path is unchanged from content the checked out commit's has at that path, then the content is already there, it will also be in the next commit, and there's nothing for `git add` to do. It's done already. A checkout of the new commit will put that content at that path. An archive of that commit will contain that content at that path.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand how Git works.

A commit and a subsequent push serve to add your changes to the repository and share them with your fellow developers. If the file is unchanged, why would you want to commit it?

If you want to want to be able to refer to specific versions of your sourcetree, you could use a *tag*. Tagging is [described in the Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). That may be the "packaging" you're looking for.

But if you want better control over *what* is deployed *where*, you need to define a [branching strategy](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

[image: git branches]
<sub>(source: [nvie.com](http://nvie.com/img/git-model@2x.png))</sub>

A commonly used strategy is to have a development branch and a master (live) branch. You develop each feature in a separate feature branch, branched off from development. If a feature is completed, you merge that branch back into development. This branch is usually deployed in a test environment which is kept up to date.
When the time comes to release a new version, you branch off a release branch from development. This is your release candidate, which is deployed on a acceptation environment. It's tested there and bugfixed if needed. Those bugfixed get merged back into development.
Once you're ready to release, you merge the release branch into master, tag it with the appropriate version, and deploy that on your production environment.
Hotfixes follow a similar path, but are branched from master, often skip the release candidate phase, and are merged back into both development and master, after which master is tagged with a new minor version.

Comment: Hi, I agreed but in our scenario we are migrating our code in package to UAT and PROD rather than individual files. So when we are in PROD we can checkout commit code where we have our all files as a part of that package. I will take a look on tag. Thanks

Comment: @rohitawat yes, tagging is exactly for that scenario where you want to deploy a specific version of your code. I'll adjust my answer to reflect this better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done code change in any file, you need not to add and push that file.

That file is already present in your repository and your next commit will not affect that.